# Mongoose gives undefined connecting db in different hosts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this in my one host

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uri = 'uri';
async function get(ID) {
await mongoose.connect(uri)
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    money: { type: Number, default: 0 }
})
const user = mongoose.model('User', User);
const person = await user.findOne({ id: ID }) || new user({ id: ID });
console.log(person.money);
}
get(3);
```

And i copy and paste to my another host/device. I added ip also. But it sends me undefined.

I want to use this schema (host 1) to my (host 2)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.